# ImageMagick eats up memory until application eventually crashes

Tags: c#, .net, memory, amazon-ec2, imagemagick

I'm using the Magick.Net-Q16-AnyCPU nuget package for resizing images that are first downloaded. On my locally machine this runs perfectly fine without problems.

I have deployed this tool (as a console app) and it is automatically run on a schedule on an AWS EC2 instance. On the EC2 instance, the tool gradually eats up all the RAM until there is none left and then crashes for obvious reasons.

I really don't understand why this would happen on the EC2 instance but not on my machine. This makes me think that it's not a code issue but rather an environment issue. I have included my code below regardless.

```
private void resizeVariant(ImageVariant imageVariant, byte[] data)
{
    using (var image = new MagickImage(data))
    {
        image.Format = MagickFormat.Jpeg;
        image.Interlace = Interlace.Jpeg; // Make image progressive

        var geometry = new MagickGeometry(imageVariant.Width, imageVariant.Height);
        geometry.FillArea = true;

        try
        {
            image.Resize(geometry);
            image.Crop(imageVariant.Width, imageVariant.Height);
            image.RePage();

            imageVariant.ResizedImageData = image.ToByteArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.Error($"Error resizing image variant for image {imageVariant.S3Key} ({imageVariant.Width},{imageVariant.Height})\n{ex.Message}\n{ex.StackTrace}");
            image.Dispose();
        }

        image.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**Framework:** .NET Core 2.0,
**EC2 instance type:** Microsoft Windows Server 2016

Comment: Just a side note, since your `image` object is wrapped in a using you don't need those extra `Dispose` calls. In your case, if there is an exception you are going to call `Dispose` 3 times.

Comment: Indeed. I added those extra ones to be 100% sure that is was being deleted after I detected this memory issue.

Comment: Are you processing more images when the tool runs on the server than when you run it locally (as in, is the tool running for a longer period of time and performing more transformations)?  Have you tried adding calls to the Garbage Collector to see if that makes a difference? I worked on some imaging software several years ago that was using GDI+ operations and we found that sometimes we would need to call for a GC in order to perform further operations. It was a hack, but it worked.

Comment: No, the source of the images is the same database which contains URLs to images. The tool then downloads the images and loads the bytes into a `MagickImage`. As for garbage collection - I've not manually called the garbage collector before. If I am running lots of these download, resize and other operations asynchronously, will there be issues from calling the garbage collector?

Comment: If you call `GC.Collect` it performs a full collection and blocks all threads. It may not solve your problem and in general is not a "recommended" solution, but since you are doing image processing with native handles, etc, it may be that forcing a GC collection may help. I am guessing your local system is not running as many asynchronous threads as the EC2 server and that could be why on the server side you are seeing this and not locally, but I am really just dart-board debugging here :)

Comment: Check your ImageMagick resources to see what memory limitations have been placed on the policy.xml in your server. In command line that can be done with `convert -list resource`. Your server may have put limitations in the policy.xml file to restrict your usage in a variety of ways. But ImageMagick should be using disk space when it cannot get memory, so it should just get slower. Sorry, I do not know .NET or EC2.

Comment: @fmw42 - sorry if this is a daft question but where do I find the policy.xml? I have published the application via Visual Studio which publishes the Magick.NET dlls wit hit.

Comment: @pstrjds - the server has 4 threads and my local machine has 8. The server has 16GB  RAM as opposed to my local 12GB. When I watch the RAM in my local task manager it just goes up and down as the images load in and out but averages out as a flat line. On the server the RAM just steadily goes upwards. It's such a dramatic difference that I just don't think it's a hardware capacity issue. I may try the GC route but it doesn't feel very nice. I have thousands of images to process and each one gets resized four times with Magick.NET so blocking every thread for each resize seems bad!

Comment: I agree - my thought would be try it and see if it helps, then maybe add a counter or something and kick off a GC after ever 100 images or something like that. Outisde of that, I have no other ideas or suggestions...best of luck!

Comment: @pstrjds - Tried added the GC to see if it made any difference but unfortunately it didn't :( - It increases more slowly but I think that's because the application as a whole was just taking longer to get through the images as expected. Thanks a lot for your suggestion though.

Comment: `@Andy Furniss`. Sorry, I do not use Windows nor know much about Magick.NET. But see http://www.imagemagick.org/script/resources.php for information about the policy.xml file and its possible locations.

Comment: @pstrjds Turns out you were actually right. The problem was that the download speed of the server was much faster than my local machine but the CPU speed was much slower. So what was happening was that the images were downloading super fast but they were being processed super slow (unlike my local machine where they were downloaded slow but processed fast). Over time this created a backlog of downloaded images that were just waiting in memory to be processed. I'm using TPL Dataflow and I believe I've solved this by using a `BufferBlock` and setting `BoundedCapacity` on subsequent TPL blocks.

Comment: @AndyFurniss - Glad you found the problem. Holding a lot of images in memory is a good way to use up a lot of memory :)